# Base Client -> getConfig is null for custom Authenticator

Tags: java, pac4j

Im using pack4j 6v and having issue of
BaseClient -> initSAMLResponseValidator -> findSessionLogoutHandler -> getConfig() is null

when IDP initiated SLO

IDP initiated single logout:
When dev server signed out, local server is not getting signed out boz of logoutHandler is null

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some issue with the initialization of the client. Can you try `client.init();` before creating your custom `Authenticator`?